# Between subjects repeated measures ANOVA in R - 5 brands, 11 measurements

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

In my research I have performed a series of measurements on 5 different brands of blocks. Each block has been inspected for deformation under incremental forces (20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110 and 120 N). The deformation for each force was measured 3 times and the mean values were assigned to each brand for a specific amount of force. I was successful in creating linear regression graphs for these 5 different brands.

Now my wish is to see whether a brand makes a significant difference in deformation values and to perform a post-hoc analysis to compare brands among themselves. In other words to compare the linear regression lines. Sorry if what I am saying makes no sense.

So far, I have tried the following commands:

```
anova(lm(Deformation~Force*Brand, data=Data))
lm(Deformation~Force, data=Data))

# and
aov.data = aov(Deformation~Force*Brand, Data)
```

I have gotten suspiciously low p-values (***) which clearly indicates that I might be doing something wrong. I would be grateful if you could help me with this issue.

```
Force   Brand   Deformation  
20  Brand1  0.65  
30  Brand1  1.23  
40  Brand1  1.25  
50  Brand1  2.39  
60  Brand1  2.45  
70  Brand1  2.93  
80  Brand1  3.13  
90  Brand1  3.57  
100 Brand1  4.68  
110 Brand1  4.84  
120 Brand1  5.33  
20  Brand2  1.24  
30  Brand2  1.11  
40  Brand2  1.6  
50  Brand2  2.13  
60  Brand2  2.69  
70  Brand2  3.60  
80  Brand2  3.90  
90  Brand2  3.99  
100 Brand2  4.51  
110 Brand2  4.74  
120 Brand2  5.98  
20  Brand3  1.21  
30  Brand3  1.37  
40  Brand3  2.56  
50  Brand3  2.49  
60  Brand3  3.17  
70  Brand3  3.33  
80  Brand3  3.38  
90  Brand3  4.2  
100 Brand3  4.22  
110 Brand3  5.22  
120 Brand3  6.28  
20  Brand4  0.92  
30  Brand4  0.89  
40  Brand4  1.2  
50  Brand4  1.67  
60  Brand4  1.98  
70  Brand4  2.25  
80  Brand4  3.8  
90  Brand4  4.17  
100 Brand4  4.94  
110 Brand4  5.4  
120 Brand4  5.76  
20  Brand5  0.69  
30  Brand5  1.26  
40  Brand5  1.61  
50  Brand5  2.17  
60  Brand5  2.07  
70  Brand5  3.35  
80  Brand5  3.27  
90  Brand5  4.13  
100 Brand5  4.25  
110 Brand5  4.59  
120 Brand5  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Repeated measure data is tricky to analyze because the errors are not independent and, therefore, the assumptions of ANOVA/linear regression are violated.

In R, there are the `lme` and `nlme` packages to deal with such issues, but if you are truly a 'novice' it might be better to either find a consultant or look at a different problem (or simplify this one).